# What cocoa applications are using the AquaticPrime Licensing System?

Tags: cocoa, licensing, system, aquaticprime

I'm thinking about using the AquaticPrime licensing system for my new mac app.  Is the framework popular?  What apps are using it?

Answer (score 2):

It's used by a lot of applications. Make sure you get the latest version of the source from its new home:

http://github.com/bdrister/AquaticPrime

The latest version fixes several bugs that are still in the version that's hosted at aquaticmac.com.

You should use the CoreFoundation version of Aquatic Prime, the Objective-C code is very easy to bypass. In fact, you shouldn't really use Objective-C for any registration-related code.

Answer (score 1):

I know that Pukka, a desktop bookmarks posting client for del.icio.us, uses AquaticPrime.